# How to label encode while iter through the list of list in python

Tags: python, dataframe, machine-learning

This is what I have done but it does not change what in the list of list(dataset) although able to print out the Label with number encoded for it.

```
dataset = [[32.3,33.5,34.2,35.3,35.3,35.7,"Light1on"],
         [52.3,52.5,53.2,54.8,55.3,55.3,"Light2on"],
         [100.3,110.2,112.3,132.5,142.3,153.5,"Fan1on"],
         [153.5,142.3,132.5,112.3,110.2,0,"Fan1off"],
         [33.2,34.5,34.6,35.3,35.3,35.8,"Light1on"],
         [33.2,35.2,35.4,36.0,36.2,42.3,"Light3on"]]

plabel = []
#dataset.to_csv('table.csv', index = None, header=True)
for row in dataset:
    print(row[6],'3')
    label = row[6]
    plabel.append(label)
    le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
    le.fit(plabel)
    label = le.transform(plabel)
    print(label)

    for column in row:
        print(column)
```

I hope it will be able label encode so i can use for my K Nearest neighbor model.

Outcome:

```
dataset = [[32.3,33.5,34.2,35.3,35.3,35.7,"Light1on"],
         [52.3,52.5,53.2,54.8,55.3,55.3,"Light2on"],
         [100.3,110.2,112.3,132.5,142.3,153.5,"Fan1on"],
         [153.5,142.3,132.5,112.3,110.2,0,"Fan1off"],
         [33.2,34.5,34.6,35.3,35.3,35.8,"Light1on"],
         [33.2,35.2,35.4,36.0,36.2,42.3,"Light3on"]]
```

Desired outcome:

```
dataset = [[32.3,33.5,34.2,35.3,35.3,35.7,0],
         [52.3,52.5,53.2,54.8,55.3,55.3,1],
         [100.3,110.2,112.3,132.5,142.3,153.5,2],
         [153.5,142.3,132.5,112.3,110.2,0,3],
         [33.2,34.5,34.6,35.3,35.3,35.8,0],
         [33.2,35.2,35.4,36.0,36.2,42.3,4]]
```

Comment: It is unclear what the problem is exactly and what you expect to happen.

Comment: @Grismar the problem was that it did not change the Label in the original list to the label encoded one

Comment: So, you want your code to update `dataset` somehow? Please provide a complete example that actually demonstrates the problem you are having and describe what outcome you expect (vs. the outcome you're getting).

Comment: @Grismar I want the label encoder to update the list however it does not update after label encoding it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use list comprehension

```
# get all sixth elements
plabel = [x[6] for x in dataset]
le.fit(plabel)
plabel = le.transform(plabel)
# replace sixth elements from each list inside 'dataset' with encoded label
dataset_encoded = [[plabel[i] if indx==6 else elem for indx, elem in enumerate(x)] for i,x in enumerate(dataset)]
>>> dataset_encoded

[[32.3, 33.5, 34.2, 35.3, 35.3, 35.7, 2],
 [52.3, 52.5, 53.2, 54.8, 55.3, 55.3, 3],
 [100.3, 110.2, 112.3, 132.5, 142.3, 153.5, 1],
 [153.5, 142.3, 132.5, 112.3, 110.2, 0, 0],
 [33.2, 34.5, 34.6, 35.3, 35.3, 35.8, 2],
 [33.2, 35.2, 35.4, 36.0, 36.2, 42.3, 4]]
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be:

1. Convert this data into a dataframe.
2. label encode the last column of this dataframe
3. convert this dataframe back to list of list.

Here you go:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(dataset)
df[6] = le.fit_transform(df[6].values)
dataset = df.values.tolist()
```

Comment if anything needs explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You question is unclear but if all you want to do is to replace the content of the 7th column in `dataset` while iterating over it, try this:

```py
dataset = [[32.3,33.5,34.2,35.3,35.3,35.7,"Light1on"],
         [52.3,52.5,53.2,54.8,55.3,55.3,"Light2on"],
         [100.3,110.2,112.3,132.5,142.3,153.5,"Fan1on"],
         [153.5,142.3,132.5,112.3,110.2,0,"Fan1off"],
         [33.2,34.5,34.6,35.3,35.3,35.8,"Light1on"],
         [33.2,35.2,35.4,36.0,36.2,42.3,"Light3on"]]

plabel = []
#dataset.to_csv('table.csv', index = None, header=True)
for i, row in enumerate(dataset.copy()):
    print(row[6],'3')
    label = row[6]
    plabel.append(label)
    le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
    le.fit(plabel)
    label = le.transform(plabel)
    print(label)
    row[6] = label
    dataset[i] = row

    for column in row:
        print(column)
```